# quiero escribir en un fichero usando dos hilos

Tags: java

mi intención es ejecutar dos hilos para escribir en un fichero pero al momento de ejecutar no me escribe nada, aclaro que el fichero lo tengo en donde están estas dos clases

```
public class Escritura extends Thread{
    String texto;
    public Escritura(String texto) {
        this.texto=texto;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
             fichero = new PrintWriter(new File("fichero.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        fichero.println(texto);

    }
    PrintWriter fichero;
}   

public class Fichero {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Escritura escritura1 = new Escritura("Hola");
            Escritura escritura2 = new Escritura("Adiós");
            escritura1.start();
            escritura2.start();

    }
}
```

Comment: no te escribe nada, o esta escribiendo en otro lado y no te estas dando cuenta (suele pasar eso). Pregunto, porque si pasara algo malo, daria un error... eso no ocurre tampoco? Lo otro que puede estar pasando es que no se esten ejecutando los hilos, ya que tu programa termina inmediatamente sin esperar que ellos terminen...

Answer (score 1):

Cuando terminas de escribir en un fichero tienes que cerrar el stream para que se guarden los cambios:

```
fichero.println(texto);

fichero.close();
```

**Adelanto:**  como cada hilo crea su instancia de PrintWriter el último que se ejecute va a reemplazar lo que escribió el primero.

Este código funcionó en mis pruebas:

```
public class Fichero {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        PrintWriter fichero = new PrintWriter(new File("/Users/carlos/Desktop/fichero.txt"));

        Escritura escritura1 = new Escritura("Hola",fichero);
        Escritura escritura2 = new Escritura("Adiós",fichero);

        escritura1.start();
        escritura2.start();

        fichero.close();
    }

}

 class Escritura extends Thread {

        String texto;
        PrintWriter fichero;

        public Escritura(String texto, PrintWriter fichero) {
            this.texto = texto;
            this.fichero = fichero;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {

           fichero.println(texto);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Entonces para que se escriba todo en el archivo seria recomendable instanciar printWriter en el constructor?

Comment: Sí, que ambos hilos compartan la misma instancia. Y llamar al `close()` en el clase Fichero cuando ambos hilos finalicen.

Comment: agradecido por tu respuesta

Answer (score 1):

No te escribe los datos por la clase `PrintWriter` creada con el constructor que espera un `File` no escribe automáticamente los datos en el disco, por lo que tienes que hacer uso del método `flush()` manualmente cuando quieras que los datos se escriban.

```
fichero.println(texto);
fichero.flush();
```

Por otra parte, si tienes dos hilos que cada uno abre el archivo en modo de escritura puedes (casi con total seguridad va a ser así) tener pérdidas de información, ya que un `Writer` puede sobrescribir los datos del otro.

Pienso que la forma correcta de hacer esto es teniendo una clase cuya función sea única y exclusivamente escribir en el fichero y que sus métodos estén sincronizados para que varios hilos puedan mandar contenido a escribir y que esta clase sea la que garantice que no habrá pérdidas de información.

Más o menos algo como esto garantiza que cuando un hilo está escribiendo y el otro intente hacerlo tenga que esperar a que el primero termine antes de poder hacerlo él.

```
public class Escritor {
    PrintWriter writer;

    public Escritor() {
        writer = new PrintWriter(new File("fichero.txt"));
    }

    public synchronized void writeln(String line) {
        writer.println(line);
        writer.flush();
    }

    // No he puesto el manejo de excepciones ni del cierre del Writer pero debe implementarse
}

public class Escritura extends Thread{
    Escritor escritor;
    String texto;

    public Escritura(Escritor escritor, String texto) {
        this.escritor = escritor;
        this.texto=texto;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        escritor.writeln(texto);
    }
}

public class Fichero {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           Escritor escritor = new Escritor();

            Escritura escritura1 = new Escritura(escritor, "Hola");
            Escritura escritura2 = new Escritura(escritor, "Adiós");
            escritura1.start();
            escritura2.start();

    }
}
```

Debes tener en cuenta que no existe un modo real de escribir físicamente en el disco duro, por lo que no tiene sentido de que cada hilo tenga acceso a escibir en el archivo físico.

Comment: cuando se acaba el main, los threads hijos no terminan inmediatamente? o quedan huerfanos? no hay que esperar que terminen?

Comment: La JVM sigue ejecutándo los hilos mientras que estos no sean de tipo daemon y por defecto las instancias de lal clase `Thread` se crean como no-daemon.